# AWS Sql Express BACKUP onto s3 bucket problem

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds

AWS Question:

I want to backup a SQL Express database onto s3 bucket.

I created a new instance of database twice (region = us-east-1**b**).

I have a s3 bucket (region = us-east-1)

I use as sql command:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
@source_db_name='helloworlddb',
@s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/helloworlddb20230515.bak',
@overwrite_S3_backup_file=1;
```

I then check the status and it fails as:

Here's the error

```
Task execution has started.

BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Express Edition (64-bit).

BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Express Edition (64-bit).

BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

helloworlddb20230515.bak: Aborting S3 upload, waiting for S3 workers to clean up and exit

helloworlddb20230515.bak: S3 processing has been aborted

BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Express Edition (64-bit).

BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Could it be because of the region in RDB containing a **'b'** are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can't compress in Sql express database files.